# Microsoft graph: get mail folder id from group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to copy an email from my inbox to the inbox of the group I'm the owner of, but i cannot get the group mail folders to read their id.

I'm looking for something similar to this api call : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders but instead of user mail folders i need the group mail folders.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to [copy an email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0) from one mailbox (yours) to another's (the group's). You need to [forward the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-forward?view=graph-rest-1.0) to the Group:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/forward
Content-type: application/json

{
  "toRecipients": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "{group's email address"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```